# Defining a Schema in PySpark when the data contains a nested array with two different DataTypes

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, rdd

I am trying to define a schema in order to create a dataframe from some data which is currently stored in a rdd. However the rdd contains some arrays which have two different DataTypes, ints and floats and therefore I am unsure how to define the schema.

An example line of data from the file in question

```
{"a":"string","b":[{"c":[[0,1.04,1.99],[1,1.03,5.26],[2,1.02,6]],"d":0.0,"e":132}]}
```

And currently my schema is this

```
StructType([
    StructField('a', StringType(), True),
    StructField('b', ArrayType(
                StructType([
                    StructField('c', ArrayType(
                        ArrayType(DoubleType()
                                  ), True), True),
                    StructField('d', DoubleType(), 
                                True),
                    StructField('e', IntegerType(), 
                                True),
   ])
])
```

However I receive the error

```
DoubleType can not accept object 0 in type <class 'int'>
```

...and vice versa when I switch to integer type.

Is there a way to include both DataTypes in PySpark ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a way to have mixed types in a single Array.

You can try to convert all the inner numbers to Float in the 'c' sublists of the input dictionary before reading them with Spark.

```
def cast_dict(dictionary):
  for subdict in dictionary['b']:
      subdict['c'] = [list(map(float, sublist)) for sublist in subdict['c']]
  return dictionary
```